# will .kube/config token expired

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

I use `.kube/config` to access Kubernetes api on a server. I am wondering does the token in config file ever get expired? How to prevent it from expire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to use kubernetes service account

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be expired after one year.  Automatic certificate renewal feature is the default on kubernetes 1.15 version unless you have explicitly disabled it during the kubeadm init phase with  --certificate-renewal=false option.

**Check expiration:**

```
    kubeadm alpha certs check-expiration
```

E.g.

CERTIFICATE                EXPIRES                  RESIDUAL TIME   EXTERNALLY MANAGED

admin.conf                 Sep 06, 2020 04:34 UTC   361d            no
apiserver                  Sep 06, 2020 04:34 UTC   361d            no
apiserver-etcd-client      Sep 06, 2020 04:34 UTC   361d            no
apiserver-kubelet-client   Sep 06, 2020 04:34 UTC   361d            no
controller-manager.conf    Sep 06, 2020 04:34 UTC   361d            no
etcd-healthcheck-client    Sep 06, 2020 04:34 UTC   361d            no
etcd-peer                  Sep 06, 2020 04:34 UTC   361d            no
etcd-server                Sep 06, 2020 04:34 UTC   361d            no
front-proxy-client         Sep 06, 2020 04:34 UTC   361d            no
scheduler.conf             Sep 06, 2020 04:34 UTC   361d            no

**Renew all certifications:**

```
  kubeadm alpha certs renew all
```

**Renew only admin.conf:**

```
  kubeadm alpha certs renew admin.conf
  cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
```

Answer (score 1):

This is OAuth provider specific. For example GKE uses [this](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method#google_id_token_authentication).

So in short, auth provider issues you a JWT token a proof you are auth, which contains a data like expiration time, according to documentation it cannot be more than 60 min in case of google accounts.

I hope it helps.